# django - having trouble selecting values based on FK relationship in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have two models that look like;

```
class Body(models.Model):
    body_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    is_adult = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    add_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    add_date = models.DateTimeField()
    edit_user = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'jdb_body'


class BodyTag(models.Model):
    body_tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.ForeignKey('Body', models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', models.CASCADE, db_column='tag')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'jdb_body_tag'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

I have a view that looks like;

```
def index(request):
latest_body_list = Body.objects.all().order_by('-body_id')
context = {
    'latest_body_list': latest_body_list
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

That view gives me a list `Body` records no problem. I am trying to display `Body` records with their corresponding `BodyTag` records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? You are not attempting to fetch `BodyTag` records anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You neeed a ManyToManyField in your class Body

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

To access

```
body = Body.objects.get(body_id=1)
tags = body.tags.all()
```

Comment: It's a one to many and your method means hardcoding every id which isn't practical. Thanks.

Comment: @UneRoue It is **not** one to many. What you are (manually) trying to construct is actually a many-to-many relation between `Body` and `Tag`. `BodyTag` is just an intermediary. The correct way to implement this is to use a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). Also the `id` chipchap31` posted is just an example, you won't hardcode them in your real implemenation.

Comment: It's a one to many. Body is one to BodyTag which is many. Reverse would be many to one. I'm not doing anything "manually".

Comment: @UneRoue You should read my comment again before getting defensive. Your m2m relation is between `Body` and `Tag`. You are emulating it using an intermediate model called `BodyTag`.

Comment: Only people who say the word "defensive" are defensive. Never even entered my mind. Think bigger, these aren't just models. They're database tables too. Body doesn't touch tag directly. The many to many is between BodyTag and Tag. Anything from Body is and will always be one to many.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
My previous answer was incorrect because I did not see the more complex relationship.  The problem is this:  You have many `BodyTag` objects to one `Body` object, but you also have many `BodyTag` objects to one `Tag` object. So as shown in the image, `BodyTag`'s **BT4** and **BT5** belong to `Body`'s **BODY1** and **BODY2**. That's why [@chipchap31](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7222295/chipchap31) is talking of a `ManyToMany` relationship.

If this is not the relationship you want, and from your comments I do not think that you want a `ManyToMany` field, then the `BodyTag` model should be either changed, or perhaps discarded.  Perhaps relate `Body` to `Tag` directly using the `ForeignKey`, and then have a field in the `Tag` model that distinguishes it with the type of tag it is, so one type would be `body`, and you can use a [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) field to show all the different types of `Tag`s.

[image]

**Previous answer (Incorrect)**
If you mean displaying these in your template, then all you have to do is follow the ForeignKey relationship backwards.  This is shown in the [documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for the views, but it would look pretty much the same in the template.  Something like:

```
{% for body in latest_body_list %}
    {{ body }}
        {% for tag in body.tag_set.all %}
            {{ tag }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `-set` is what tells django to look backward in the `ForeignKey` relationship.

A perhaps better way, also shown in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) would be to define a `related_name` in your ForeignKey:

```py
class BodyTag(models.Model):
    body_tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.ForeignKey('Body', models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', models.CASCADE, db_column='tag')
```

Then your template could be written a little better:

```
{% for body in latest_body_list %}
    {{ body }}
        {% for tag in body.tags.all %}
            {{ tag }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why is related name better than set?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I have used _set successfully in the past, but these particular examples don't provide an error but also do not display the tags. I will do a little reading and see if I can deduce why. Thanks

Comment: `related_name` can sometimes make the backward relationship easier to read and understand, that is all.  I think I now see our error, and what chipchap31 was trying to show.  I've edited my answer, @UneRoue to show what I think is the problem.  And @chipchap31 I think I see what you are saying now.